# Change CSS menu heading hover attribute to orange while hovering

Tags: html, css

How can I make the menu-category color attribute change to orange when hovered and NOT remain orange while hovering other child items?  Is this too tricky or am I not being clear enough? Please let me know.  Thank you for help.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LmWk2/

```
<nav class="main-nav">
<ul>
<li class="menu-category">Title 1
<ul>
<a href="#"><li class="menu-item">Item 1</li></a>
<a href="#"><li class="menu-item">Item 2</li></a>
<a href="#"><li class="menu-item">Item 3</li></a>
<a href="#"><li class="menu-item">Item 4</li></a>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-category">Title 2
<ul>
<a href="#"><li class="menu-item">Item 1</li></a>
<a href="#"><li class="menu-item">Item 2</li></a>
<a href="#"><li class="menu-item">Item 3</li></a>
<a href="#"><li class="menu-item">Item 4</li></a>
<a href="#"><li class="menu-item">Item 5</li></a>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-category">Title 3
<ul>
<a href="#"><li class="menu-item">Item 1</li></a>
<a href="#"><li class="menu-item">Item 2</li></a>
<a href="#"><li class="menu-item">Item 3</li></a>
<a href="#"><li class="menu-item">Item 4</li></a>
<a href="#"><li class="menu-item">Item 5</li></a>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-category">Title 4
<ul>
<a href="#"><li class="menu-item">Item 1</li></a>
<a href="#"><li class="menu-item">Item 2</li></a>
<a href="#"><li class="menu-item">Item 3</li></a>
<a href="#"><li class="menu-item">Item 4</li></a>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I'm using latest Chrome and I don't see any problem..? The orange color does not remain orange when hovering other items..

Comment: I would like Title 1, Title 2, Title 3, Title 4 to behave the same as "Item 1, Item 2, Item 3" when it comes to font color on hover.

Comment: Why oh why are you wrapping `<li>` elements with `<a>` tags? If you put the links in the list items, it would make a lot more sense semantically.

Comment: I understand what you are saying.  Could you provide an example of how I should properly link an <li>?

Comment: I think that you want the menu items to behave like buttons (click anywhere in the box) instead of text links?

Comment: Yes that's correct Marc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer addresses the color-change-on-hover issue and the related issue of making the links behave like buttons (block like) instead of text links.

As pointed out by a previous post, it is a good idea to wrap the title tag in a container, I chose `h4` but almost anything will do.  Also, for semantic reasons, but the link tags inside the list-item tags:

```
<nav class="main-nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="menu-category"><h4>Title 1</h4>
            <ul>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        ...
        ...
        ...
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The essential changes to the CSS are as follows.

For the title text:

```
.main-nav ul li.menu-category h4 {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:5px 15px 8px 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.main-nav ul li.menu-category h4:hover {
    color:#FB8521;
}
```

The trick here is to set `display: inline-block` to the element wrapping the title text.  Because I chose to use `h4`, I needed to zero out the margin and set the font-weight to normal to keep with your previous styling.  Also, add padding to make the text area large so you can trigger the hover effect without actually mousing over the text.

For the sub-menu items, set the `a` tags to have `display: block`, that way the link's active area fills up the width of the sub-menu panel.  Add padding as needed.

```
.menu-category .menu-item a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}
.menu-category .menu-item a:hover {
    color:#FB8521;
}
```

You can see the working demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/jvgkG/

**PS**

There is flexibility in this layout with regards to how the hover works.  I assumed that the title text reverts to white when you mouse onto the secondary menu items, but I could set it up so that the title remains orange as you move over the secondary menu.

Also, you can style the default link color as you see fit.

Comment: Very well explained.  Thank you.  I am going to start implementing this right away.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to add another element that wraps only the title:

```
<li class="menu-category"><span class="menu-category-title">Title 1</span>

.menu-category-title:hover {
    color: orange;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/LmWk2/1/ (for TITLE1)

Comment: This is what im going for, but I need it to affect the entire container.  Your code only changes when hovering the text.

Comment: @Chaddly Please clarify the area that triggers when "Title 1" changes color.  When you say "entire container", which element are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry abou that, <li class="menu-category">Title X</li>

Comment: Adding a wrapper to the text title is a good idea since it provides an easily accessed hook for adding creative styling and interactive effects using pseudo-classes or JavaScript. +1